# Resize Div pure CSS if possible

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML structure:

```
<div class="outer">
<div class="inner">
<a href="#"/>
<a href="#"/>
<a href="#"/>
</div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
div.outer{
    position:relative;
    height:177px;
    width: 495px;
    margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
} 
div.inner{
    position: absolute; 

}
```

How is it possible to resize the outer div dinamically ? Height min-max does not work. Thank you !

Comment: Resize the outer div dynamically in response to what?

Comment: which event do you want to cause the outer div to resize? what are the limitations?

Comment: I want it to have a min and max height. Let's say min of 59 px, max of 590px.

Comment: That is I try to mimic default min and max height CSS behaiviour. Somehow because div inner is already modified via JS (transition effect), when I set the outer div's min and max size, only the min height is taken. I want it to simply adjust itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this to work the way I think you want it to work, then you'd need to use all three declarations: `min-height`, `height` and `max-height`, with the `height` being a relative measure, and the `min-height` and `max-height` both used to constrain that relative sizing to an appropriate minimum or maximum. For example:

```
.outer {
    overflow: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 50%;
    border: 2px solid #000; /* The above just for aesthetics, adjust to change */
    min-height: 100px;
    height: 50%;
    max-height: 1000px;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NR72p/1/)

In the demo, resize the window to cause the 'preview' pane to expand/contract to see the effects.